# Rails 3.2 Simplify Controller with Model Methods on has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, refactoring, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Most questions I've seen with skinnying up controllers deals with a simple model relationships.  My question is if you're updating a many to many form with multiple parameters and their associated arrays, how do you simplify the task by moving it all to a model method?  For example take a look at the ridiculously large controller below.  What's the simplest way of dealing with this unholy mess?  I'm not looking for a syntactically perfect answer but need a general consensus on a direction to go with this.

```
def update
  @shipment = Shipment.joins(:products).find(params[:id], :readonly => false)
  @shipment.update_attributes(params[:shipment])
  @shipment_products = params[:product_shipments]
  @product_shipment_array= array_from_hash(@shipment_products)


  @shipment.product_shipments.each do |product_shipment|
    product_shipment.update_attributes(:qty_shipped => params[:product_shipments][product_shipment.id.to_s][:qty_shipped], :pickup_item => params[:product_shipments][product_shipment.id.to_s][:pickup_item])
  end
  @product_shipment_array.each do |p|
    if  p['old_pickup_item'] == "true" and p['pickup_item'].to_i==0
      @difference = (p['qty_shipped'].to_i)
      Product.mark_open_shipment(@difference, p['product_id'])

    elsif p['old_pickup_item'] == "false" and p['pickup_item'].to_i==1
      @difference = -(p['old_qty_shipped'].to_i)
      Product.mark_open_shipment(@difference, p['product_id'])
    else
      @difference = -(p['old_qty_shipped'].to_i - p['qty_shipped'].to_i)
      Product.mark_open_shipment(@difference, p['product_id'])
    end

  end

  respond_with @shipment, :location => shipments_url
end
```

and in my model I want to declare a model method something like this

```
Class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  .
  .
  .      
  def update_shipment_attributes
    #all business logic
  end

end
```

In the hopes of getting my controller down to something like this or something similar:

```
def update
  @shipment = Shipment.joins(:products).find(params[:id], :readonly => false)
  @shipment.update_attributes(params[:shipment])
  @shipment_products = params[:product_shipments]

  Shipment.update_shipment_attributes

  respond_with @shipment, :location => shipments_url     
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few approaches you can take to achieve what you want:

1. [Look into using nested forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. With nested attributes, your controller `edit` method will only need to share one `@shipment` instance variable with a nested collection of shipment_products.
2. Consider having your `update` action only call `update_attributes`. When you're using nested attributes properly, this should be the the only model call you need because it will implicitly populate the attributes for its `shipment_products`.
3. In your `shipment_products` model, use an `after_save` callback to mark the open shipments. But beware, your shipment_products model should *not* use the word `Product` (capitalized). Instead, it should rely on its `belongs_to` relation to call `product.mark_open_shipment(difference)`. `difference` should be refactored into an instance method on product_shipments. The callbacks and update_attributes will all run in one transaction, which will ensure atomicity.

Comment: I mainly just want to refactor the code because I have achieved the behavior I'm looking for.  I'm looking for a more specific example on how to move the business logic I have into its own model method.  I'm stuck on how to pass parameters and variables into a model method.

Comment: The answer I gave moves the business logic into the model. If you absolutely must use `#update_shipment_attributes` (not recommended, as it is an anti-pattern), then you should call it on the instance, not the class. E.g. `@shipment.update_shipment_attributes(attributes)`. Furthermore, using that method will result in multiple transactions, meaning your data will be incorrect / inconsistent if the second transaction fails. Consider using `update_attributes` and callbacks instead.